# React component not updating when redux state is updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am firing an action to do some toggle functionality, however, my react component is not re rendering even though the redux state is

```
const Countries = ({ countries, toggleCountry }) => (
  <div>
    <h4> All Countries </h4>
    <div className="container">
      {countries.map((country, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className={`countryContainer ${country.visited ? 'visited' : ''}`}
        >
          <img src={country.flag} alt="countryFlag" />
          <p className="countryName"> {country.name} </p>
          <button onClick={() => toggleCountry(country.name)}>
            {country.visited ? 'undo' : 'visited'}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = ({ countries }) => ({
  countries
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      toggleCountry
    },
    dispatch
  );

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Countries);
```

when I click this button it is correctly toggling in the redux state but the component does not re render to show the new button label or change the class name

this is my reducer:

const initialState = []

```
export default(state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'UPDATE_INITIAL_COUNTRIES':
      return state.concat(action.countries)
    case 'UPDATE_COUNTRY_VISITED':
      return state.map(country => (
        country.name === action.name ? {...country, visited: !country.visited} : country
      ))
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and my action creator

```
export const toggleCountry = countryName => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_COUNTRY_VISITED', countryName })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `toggleCountry` action creator code?

Comment: @VuHuuCuong done

Comment: And the corresponding reducer too :)

Comment: @VuHuuCuong also done

Comment: flips sake, fixed it. was using `name` instead of ` countryName` *facepalm*

Comment: Be careful with the code's typo :)

Answer (score 2):

The action expects `action.name`, but instead receives `action.countryName`

The problem is here

```
export const toggleCountry = countryName => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_COUNTRY_VISITED', countryName })
  }
}
```

fix:

```
export const toggleCountry = name => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_COUNTRY_VISITED', name })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `country.name === action.name ? {...country, visited: !country.visited} : country` 
you are searching for action.name but in below declaration you have not given payload a proper name

```
export const toggleCountry = countryName => {
      return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_COUNTRY_VISITED', countryName })
      }
    }
```

Fix:

```
export const toggleCountry = countryName => {
      return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_COUNTRY_VISITED', name :countryName })
      }
    }
```